# C++ : How can I parallelize an n-ary operation on n ranges?

Tags: c++, c++17

A binary operation in two ranges can be parallelized in this way:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>

std::vector<int> add(const std::vector<int>& A, const std::vector<int>& B) {
    assert(A.size() == B.size());
    std::vector<int> C;
    C.reserve(A.size());
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(),
        std::back_inserter(C), std::plus<>{});
    return C;
}
```

I want to extend this to n ranges with summing n arguments (or whatever n-ary operation). The number of ranges, n, is not known in advance at compile time.

`std::transform` doesn't offer to do this. How can I do?

I want something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

std::vector<int> addn (const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& Rs) {

    const std::size_t n = Rs[0].size();
    assert(std::ranges::all_of(Rs, [&n](const auto& R){return R.size() == n;}));
    std::vector<int> res(n);
    // want to parallelize
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (const auto& R : Rs) {
            res[i] += R[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @G.Sliepen The assumption is that the all range has the same length. Therefore the list of vectors is actually a 2-d matrix. What I want to do is a generalized parallelized ReduceSum operation.. https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/Operators.md#ReduceSum

Comment: @G.Sliepen Added a simple example of (unparallelized) ReduceSum. In the actual code, the argument will be a vector of forward iterators on different ranges with the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nested for loop, and want to convert that to using STL algorithms, then generally the trick is to nest STL algorithms. If you wanted to sum each row, then the for loop would look like:

```
for (auto row: Rs) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto col: row)
        sum += R;
    res.push_back(sum);
}
```

And then the conversion to algorithms would be relatively easy: the inner loop can be replaced with [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
for (auto row: Rs) {
    res.push_back(std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0);
}
```

And then the outer loop can be converted to a call to `std::transform()`. The final function would look like:

```
std::vector<int> sum_each_row(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& Rs) {
    const std::size_t n = Rs.size();
    std::vector<int> res(n);

    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq, Rs.begin(), Rs.end(), res.begin(),
                   [](auto&& row) {
        return std::accumulate(row.begin(), row.end(), 0);
    });

    return res;
}
```

You could use `std::reduce(std::execution::par_unseq, ...)` instead of `std::accumulate()` for even further parallelization, but most likely just having the outer loop parallelized would be enough.

However, if we want to sum every column, things start to get messier. What we can do is do a parallel transform over the elements of the first row in `Rs`, and try to get the index of that element, like so:

```
std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
               Rs[0].begin(), Rs[0].end(), res.begin(),
               [&](auto&& col) {
    size_t i = &col - &Rs[0].front();
    ...
}
```

Once we have the column index `i`, we can either do a manual `for`-loop to sum that column, or again use a similar trick to be able to use a STL algorithm. Here is a possible implementation:

```
std::vector<int> sum_each_column(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& Rs) {
    const std::size_t n = Rs[0].size();
    std::vector<int> res(n);

    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
                   Rs[0].begin(), Rs[0].end(), res.begin(),
                   [&](auto&& col) {
        size_t i = &col - &Rs[0].front();
        return std::transform_reduce(Rs.begin(), Rs.end(), 0, std::plus<>(),
                                     [i](auto&& row) {
            return row[i];
        });
    });

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I found that this solution is wrong. I was mistaken to accept this answer. We can't accumulate each row to make the result. What I wanted was to reduce each "column" when "rows" are given. (Upvoted anyway to thank your effort.)

Comment: @trozenca Uhm, you should not upvote things for effort, you should upvote *correct* answers and downvote *incorrect* answers, otherwise there is no incentive to provide correct answers :) I'll try to update my answer later.

Comment: @frozenca Updated to include a working solution that sums each column.